# Was there ever a Linux kernel driver for accessing disks via BIOS?

Tags: hard-disk, bios, linux, driver

If there is some piece of PC compatible hardware where there are no (publicly) existing drivers for Linux, the only option is to [access the disk with BIOS calls](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3041). I'm aware that this imposes restrictions on the maximum size of disk and/or partition to be used.

Has some old Linux Kernel featured such a driver? Searching online yields a lot of irrelevant hits about more modern systems and their particular booting challenges.

My goal is to be able to run Linux from the emulated disk on an old [AS/400 IPCS card](https://try-as400.pocnet.net/wiki/The_Integrated_PC_Servers). OS drivers are available only for Windows NT 4 and 2k.

Comment: The issue is PC / PC compatible BIOS disk calls are real mode only so past something like GRUB in the early / pre-boot process they wouldn't be used by Linux.

Comment: The kernel cannot, actually; `vesafb` only calls the video BIOS once at boot, before the kernel is properly started (mode-switching is impossible afterwards), while `uvesafb` delegates BIOS calls to userspace.

Comment: Some calls can be done using something like ibx86 but mainly it was done for mode setting for displays as that wasn't standardized in hardware and varied a lot between different video chips/cards.

Comment: @user3840170 in older systems calling video BIOS actually worked fine; the VESA driver for X did this for a long time, and X had to use it to initialize a second graphics card. IIRC it doesn't work for disk BIOS services, because they need some tables that are only present in real mode.

Comment: The link you provided suggested it was possible to run Linux on it with a USB floppy... I was also going to suggest looking into whether you could PXE boot is (diskless boot, and then possibly NFS mount if you needed to be able to write stuff) but it doesn't sound like it has a "real" network card to support that (though given it supports Netware, not positive) [Neither of these answer your question, but might be other things to look at for your underlying challenge]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At first, I was convinced that such a driver had never been written.  But in fact, there was one; although it was never merged into upstream Linux.  Thanks to [@Joshua for pointing me to it](/q/16425/15334#comment97184_16435).

The driver is part of Yggdrasil Linux/GNU/X, a LiveCD widely recognised as the first commercial Linux distribution.  The source code for the driver is found for example within the directory `/usr/src/linux/drivers/bios/` on the Fall 1994 release of the disc (and remains included in a patch form on the Winter 1997 software compilation CD), along with a driver that delegates CD-ROM accesses to MSCDEX.  The README file included with the patch containing the driver makes it very clear how stable the driver was considered:

> This driver is still experimental, it has worked for numerous people, but
> it has failed for others.  Use at your own risk.  I only recommend this
> to people who are interested in using it as a boot strap for developing
> new device drivers or for acessing some bios routines which need only
> be used rarely such as laptop power down functions.

The mechanism employed is pretty simple: each time the driver needs to perform a BIOS call, it switches into real mode, performs the call, then switches back into protected mode.  This has all the drawbacks you would expect: any I/O operation would suspend every other thread of execution, the kernel had to perform extra copies between kernel memory and conventional memory, and if the BIOS invocation went off the rails, it took down the whole system.  (Concurrency? SMP? Locking? Memory protection? What are you talking about? Ah, simpler times.)

Given the architecture of the kernel, this was the best one could do.  The kernel has never had any facility to invoke 16-bit code from kernel mode during normal operation (after early boot); even the APM driver [only ever supported the 32-bit protected-mode entry point](https://github.com/schwabe/davej-history/blob/a1142b87288fbdd7ee4a847c5d1dfc09ef803ab7/drivers/char/apm_bios.c#L1058-L1061).  While support for 16-bit protected mode and virtual 8086 mode has been added, it was only ever driven by userspace, i.e. by DOSEMU, Wine and (userspace) VBE video drivers.  The closest Linux got to a mechanism to enter virtual 8086 mode from kernel mode is [in a patch for the `vesafb` driver in Linux 2.6.20](https://web.archive.org/web/20101110072651id_/http://dev.gentoo.org/%7Espock/projects/vesafb-tng/archive/vesafb-tng-1.0-rc2-2.6.20-rc2.patch) that was never merged into the upstream kernel; the patch’s successor, `uvesafb`, likewise invoked the video BIOS from userspace.

Although the BIOS and MSCDEX drivers were never merged upstream, the block device numbers they used were listed as reserved in the upstream kernel from version 1.3.22 (which was the first to even have a file listing all block device numbers: both [the BIOS driver’s](https://github.com/schwabe/davej-history/blob/8f0ec1f9369b4199654a6dc5fd1b06268bdf0c15/Documentation/devices.txt#L258-L265) and [the MSCDEX driver’s](https://github.com/schwabe/davej-history/blob/8f0ec1f9369b4199654a6dc5fd1b06268bdf0c15/Documentation/devices.txt#L225-L228) numbers are present) until [their removal in 2.6.30](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/4/3/234).

As for “how it worked” in the other sense… the hard disk driver works surprisingly well, actually: no mysterious “tables” seem to be missing.  I did some light testing in 86Box: after choosing a period-appropriate configuration, booting the system from an included LILO floppy image and activating the driver with `bios_hd=1`, it would access the raw disk, partitions and file systems just fine.

As for the MSCDEX CD driver, trying that one was… less successful.  This is what I got when I booted into MS-DOS 6.22 in 86Box 3.5, then launched Yggdrasil from the CD with a provided batch file:

```
MSCDEX CD-Rom Driver Copyright (C) 1994 Yggdrasil Computing, Inc.
MSCDEX CD-Rom Driver found 1 Drive
drive letter found: D
— [irrelevant kernel logs cut] —
MSCDEX error: AX=0x15
MSCDEX: Invalid Drive or other error
MSCDEX: Checking drive D
MSCDEX Drive Status: 0x00000000 return status: 0x8102
MSCDEX Reset: status: 0x8102
MSCDEX error: AX=0x15
MSCDEX: Invalid Drive or other error
MSCDEX: Checking drive D
MSCDEX Drive Status: 0x00000000 return status: 0x8102
MSCDEX Reset: status: 0x8102
MSCDEX error: AX=0x15
MSCDEX: Invalid Drive or other error
MSCDEX: Checking drive D
MSCDEX Drive Status: 0x00000000 return status: 0x8102
MSCDEX Reset: status: 0x8102
```

And it just went on like that.  And this was the only configuration where booting into Linux didn’t outright crash the emulated machine; I have not investigated if the emulator is to blame for this.  Still, it was better than PCem, where it crashed the emulator itself.  QEMU didn’t do better: it hung even earlier, while testing the `hlt` opcode.

---

If you want to run a more modern kernel, your best bet may be to write a driver for this device yourself: either via reverse-engineering or by creating a virtual 8086 mode monitor/emulator to run the BIOS-based driver in, like userspace VBE drivers do.  (You may even attempt to port the Yggdrasil driver to modern kernels, but by no means will it be trivial, if possible at all: kernel APIs have changed significantly in the meantime.)  In the general case, I expect the latter approach to be very fragile, as the ROM BIOS code may assume that it has the entirety of the hardware at its disposal, make all sorts of assumptions about its state, and attempt to perform operations that are difficult to emulate, especially from userspace code. In particular it may try to:

- raise a System Management Interrupt (the BIOS on a laptop I am writing this on does that),
- turn off interrupts to guarantee atomicity,
- reconfigure the Programmable Interrupt Controller and other hardware,
- perform DMA transfers,

And many other things.  Most of these considerations usually do not apply to video BIOSes, as those usually confine themselves to operating on the video hardware itself.  As such, they only require access to I/O ports and memory, and those are rather easy to provide.

Also note that the BIOS interrupt calls were not designed to be reentrant or execute under the supervision of a multitasking operating system (they were [designed as drivers for DOS, after all](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3042/15334)). Given that, environments which *do* provide BIOS-based disk drivers are either single-tasking systems like DOS anyway or take some pains to ensure that BIOS calls have exclusive access to all the hardware (including the CPU) and do not interfere with anything else:

- GNU GRUB 2, a boot loader containing both BIOS and “bare-metal” disk drivers, is a single-tasking, pure ring-0 environment that contains some logic to [ensure firmware-based and native drivers are never used at the same time](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/disk/i386/pc/biosdisk.c?h=384091967d25ad7fe2fc0930b11adb23974bfeb9#n660);
- The [real-mode mapper in Windows 9x](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071224-00/?p=24063) (i.e. its DOS/BIOS file system driver) executes real-mode code in ring 0 and guards it by [the critical section](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140912-00/?p=44083), which is essentially a global kernel lock (cf. Linux removing the Big Kernel Lock entirely in version 2.6.39)

All of the above told, things are not hopeless: if you stick to a narrow goal of writing a driver that works with a specific BIOS whose behaviour is known so that you can apply workarounds specific to your firmware (as opposed to creating a fully general solution), there is a good chance it might actually work quite reliably.  Especially if the BIOS comes from an option ROM on an extension card, as those are much less free to assume things about other hardware that may be present.

Comment: "The kernel has never had any facility to invoke 16-bit code from kernel mode in normal operation" Maybe the kernel didn't, but it was easily possible, as I already wrote above in the comment. For example, have a look at the code for the old [VBE X driver](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xserver/blob/xorg-server-1.12.4/hw/xfree86/vbe/vbe.c), you can see that it calls interrupt 0x10 in the BIOS.

Comment: That’s a userspace driver, using the `vm86` syscall; its existence doesn’t refute what I said. Video drivers can get away with executing BIOS calls from userspace, because the video BIOS tends to be relatively isolated from the rest of the firmware (e.g. the SMM handler); running it doesn’t require full ring 0 privileges, just I/O port access. I don’t understand why you downvoted a correct answer: a BIOS-based disk driver has never existed and for the reasons I listed, it’s not going to be trivial to write one.

Comment: And the kernel could equally well get away with calling the BIOS, using it's own implementation of the vm86 syscall (which means "never has had any facility" is just wrong). It doesn't do that, because the problem is that in particular the disk BIOS calls (unlike the video BIOS) need specific tables in memory, which get thrown away after the switch to protected mode. So instead of trying to salvage this across different BIOSes, it was simpler, cleaner and more efficient to just have the kernel provide drivers. And that's the real reason, not because "it cannot be done".

Comment: The ‘kernel could equally well get away’—but didn’t. Were this so easy, `uvesafb` wouldn’t need a userspace helper. The kernel ‘could equally well get away’ not throwing away any tables (in fact, nothing in conventional memory is thrown away as far as I can see); it can set up any memory map it wants. The real difficulty is in ensuring the BIOS can access all the hardware it needs without disturbing anything else. And I never just said ‘it cannot be done’: I pointed to specific difficulties that will have to be overcome, which aren’t just ensuring some unspecified ‘tables’ are present.

Comment: Thanks @all for all the explanations and lively discussion! I did not expect to attract that much attention with my question. Apparently I was wrong. :-)

Comment: @dirkt: I'm confused. Why do the tables get thrown away when they survive when booting MS-DOS? The bottom 4KB of RAM is preserved in both cases as is the shave-off region at the top of 640KB should the memory range call say any was shaved off. As for the rest, I've never seen a Linux disk driver that used bios calls, but the old major/minor tables had reserved device ids for such a device. I think the idea was to not emulate it, but transfer back to real mode, call the BIOS interrupt, and transfer back.

Comment: @Joshua You remember in which kernel versions the reservation was present?

Comment: @user3840170: 2.0.something. That's the best I can do.

Comment: Just ran into this video. I can't verify but it looks like somebody actually did implement it, and that's why there was the reservation. https://youtu.be/Cynd0guSUvM?t=868

Comment: Well, so much for ‘no such driver has ever been written’. I looked at the LiveCD, and indeed there it is, with source code. I am not editing it into the answer until the strike is over, though.

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly possible for both userspace and the kernel to access the BIOS. In fact, the kernel offers a [vm86 syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vm86.2.html), which is an emulation of real mode.

This syscall was used for a long time in the `vesa` driver for X (before it got replaced with the `vesafb` kernel driver; see e.g. [here](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xserver/blob/xorg-server-1.12.4/hw/xfree86/vbe/vbe.c) for some code), there are projects like [Linux Real-Mode Interface](https://github.com/mqudsi/lrmi) which use it to provide a DPMI-like interface to real mode BIOS, etc.

However, the problem with using the BIOS calls for disk access is that those depend on in-memory tables that are not preserved when Linux boots – in particular because different BIOSes do this differently. Therefore it was much easier and cleaner for Linux to just provide its own drivers for disk access than to try to deal with this mess.

That's why the kernel never featured such a driver.

So for your particular case, you'd need to write the drivers in one way or other. You can either go through the trouble to figure out where how the BIOS of the IPCS stores the tables, or you can figure out how your existing drivers work. Both would presumably have some way to communicate with the AS/400 host to transfer blocks from and to the emulated disk. So reverse engineering is needed anyhow, and then you can write the Linux drivers for it.

This looks like a fun project, but it probably can be quite time consuming.

Comment: Providing in-memory tables is trivial: just mmap `/dev/mem`. Linux apparently preserves enough conventional memory to make [projects like ‘DOS Subsystem for Linux’](https://github.com/charliesome/doslinux) actually somewhat viable. Preserving ‘in-memory tables’ is a non-issue. The real problem is keeping the BIOS from stepping on other drivers’ invariants.

Comment: The other thing is, [`vesafb` cannot do mode switching at runtime](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/vesafb.html#x11), so it didn’t fully replace the X driver: X had to do mode switching (i.e. calling the video BIOS) on its own.  The predecessor to `uvesafb`, `vesafb-tng` required [invasive kernel patching](https://web.archive.org/web/20101110072651id_/http://dev.gentoo.org/~spock/projects/vesafb-tng/archive/vesafb-tng-1.0-rc2-2.6.20-rc2.patch) to invoke 16-bit code from a kernel thread; this has never made its way upstream. `uvesafb` just calls `vm86` from a userspace helper daemon.

Comment: @user3840170 **Providing** them is trivial, you don't even need `/dev/mem` for that. **Capturing** the existing tables at boot is not, because every BIOS does that differently. Which means the standard Linux boot just throws them out. And as your link shows, it's perfectly possible to invoke 16-bit code from a kernel thread. It's just not something you want in the Linux kernel, for architectural reasons. So the answer is not "it can't be done", the answer is "people don't do it because it's too ugly to make it work".

Comment: @dirkt Reverse-Engineering might be fun but it's clearly far beyond my capabilities, in terms of skill, knowledge, patience, and time. Also, since at leat the #2850 is maxed out with 128 MB of ram, the driver in a current kernel (with a current userland) might be somewhat useless: Committed_as shows as little as 50 MB used in a minimal install, but apt-get update itself will not run with less than 256 MB.

Comment: @PoC Embedded variants of Linux run with a lot less RAM, so you can certainly tweak things. Also, the link you provided mentions that Linux drivers did exists, maybe they (and the Linux version they belonged to) can still be found somewhere?

Comment: @dirkt You made a point. :-) Also, Linux drivers exist as binary blob, precompiled for certain 2.6 kernels only. These are from a newer release of OS/400 (V5R4). I'm not sure if the newer drivers work with older OS/400 releases. Yet, I lack the hardware on my model 800 to actually install such an old Linux and transfer the virtual disks over to my model 150 (running V4R5) to actually test if the drivers work.

Comment: @PoC No network, no serial connection, no line-out/mic? Data can be transferred over almost anything... And if you actually have the binary blob for the Linux drivers, and know for which kernels they are precompiled, reverse-engineering becomes *a lot* easier. If the "blob" is a module and not a monolithic kernel, it will even have symbol references.

Comment: I never said ‘it can’t be done’, stop putting words in my mouth. Of course, you can do literally anything with a large enough patch – you can even make Linux binary-identical to the Windows NT kernel. You have to draw the line somewhere for terms like ‘possible to do with Linux’ to be meaningful. Since this never-upstreamed patch requires modifying the kernel core (as opposed to being wholly contained in a stand-alone module), I don’t think it qualifies.

Comment: And my first link shows that Linux is capable of capturing an *entire copy of DOS running in conventional memory* (including any mysterious ‘tables’), and continuing to run it under a (userspace) virtual 8086 monitor. Nothing is ‘discarded’. At least under SeaBIOS, that copy of DOS is perfectly capable of using the BIOS to access the disk. Problem is, other BIOSes may require more hardware access than this minimal VMM seems to provide.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks. I know there are possibilities. So far, they're beyond what I'm able to do. But I appreciate your efforts to convince me. :-)